# XML schema: how do I restrict a wildcard type to have an attribute group

Tags: xml, schema

The simplest motivation being that I want a way to describe an array of objects, that can have any particular type and attributes as necessary, but must have a common attribute group:

```
<xs:element name="objects">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="object-attributes"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This is a similar idea to what I'm looking for, but it also requires the parent `objects` element to participate in `object-attributes`, which doesn't make sense in my context.

```
<xs:element name="objects">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax">
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="object-attributes"/>
      </xs:any>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Alternatively, this is what I feel makes the most sense intuitively, but the XML specification indicates that an `xs:any` wildcard element can't contain any subelements except annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the names of elements that are allowed to match a wildcard, and if you do that you require them to match a schema declaration of that element (using processContents). But if you don't restrict the name, you can't restrict the type, which means you can't constrain what attributes are allowed to appear.

As always the fallback is to use XSD 1.1 assertions.